# Why can't CLISP call certain functions with uninterned names?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, clisp

I've written an ad hoc parser generator that creates code to convert an old and little known 7-bit character set into unicode. The call to the parser generator expands into a bunch of `defun`s enclosed in a `progn`, which then get compiled. I only want to expose one of the generated `defun`s--the top-level one--to the rest of the system; all the others are internal to the parser and only get called from within the dynamic scope of the top-level one. Therefore, the other `defun`s generated have uninterned names (created with `gensym`). This strategy works fine with SBCL, but I recently tested it for the first time with CLISP, and I get errors like:

```
*** - FUNCALL: undefined function #:G16985
```

It seems that CLISP can't handle functions with uninterned names. (Interestingly enough, the system compiled without a problem.) **EDIT:** It seems that it can handle functions with uninterned names in most cases. See the answer by Rörd below.

My questions is: Is this a problem with CLISP, or is it a limitation of Common Lisp that certain implementations (e.g. SBCL) happen to overcome?

**EDIT:**

For example, the **macro expansion** of the top-level generated function (called `parse`) has an expression like this:

```
(PRINC (#:G75735 #:G75731 #:G75733 #:G75734) #:G75732)
```

Evaluating this expression (by calling `parse`) causes an error like the one above, even though the function is definitely defined within the very same macro expansion:

```
(DEFUN #:G75735 (#:G75742 #:G75743 #:G75744) (DECLARE (OPTIMIZE (DEBUG 2)))
 (DECLARE (LEXER #:G75742) (CONS #:G75743 #:G75744))
 (MULTIPLE-VALUE-BIND (#:G75745 #:G75746) (POP-TOKEN #:G75742)
 ...
```

The two instances of #:G75735 are definitely the same symbol--not two different symbols with the same name.  As I said, this works with SBCL, but not with CLISP.

**EDIT:**

SO user Joshua Taylor has pointed out that this is due to [a long standing CLISP bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/bugs/180/).

Comment: The symbols in the printed representation are the same. However, when you write something like `#:foo` the reader creates a new symbol, so, e.g., typing in your REPL, you get `(eq '#:foo '#:foo) ;=> nil`.  Did you try to call the function by typing its name in?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor As I said in the post, the symbols are the same symbol. The macro calls `gensym` just once and places the result in several places in the expansion. Of course, reading the macro expansion would cause two different symbols to be created, but that's not what's happening.

Comment: Can you produce some direct code that reproduces this problem.  I can  write a macro that defines some mutually recursive functions named by symbols that are uninterned, and it works fine in CLISP.  See, e.g., http://pastebin.com/7MNGkgta .  It's got two functions with uninterned names, and one with name that makes it easy to call, and it seems to work OK.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I really can't do that without simplifying it to the point where, so far as I know, it might begin to work. If you want to email me (nbtrap AT nbtrap DOT com), I can send you the actual project code, which, you'll see, runs fine with SBCL but not with CLISP. The problem is the macro that generates the parser is just too complex to simplify into an example here, though the code it generates is rather simple (a collection of huge `case` expressions).

Comment: Well, that's the idea right?  Get to the point where it works, take one step backward, and ask what the difference was. That will be a question that you'll almost definitely get a conclusive answer for.  Another thing I'd suggest for debugging is using the optional string argument to `gensym` to get some more readable macroexpansions.  It shouldn't affect this issue, but it might make tracking it down easier.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor That wouldn't really explain why it works with SBCL and not CLISP. As I said, the macro expansion is rather simple--it's just huge. *And* CLISP compiles the code just fine.

Comment: If there's nothing the matter with the code, then it shouldn't be surprising that it works in SBCL.  If's it's a CLISP bug, then you'd want to find the place where it _starts_ to occur.  If it's a rather simple macro expansion, then it shouldn't be too hard to come up with a simpler example that replicates the problem, right?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I meant that the code generated by the macro is simple and analogous to REPL examples that others have given here (which happen to work). Please see the second edit to Rord's answer and the comments under it--I think he's on to something.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor You're right though. Sooner or later, I'm going to have to come up with a simple example. Especially if I have to file a bug report.

Comment: Oh, some additional googling may have turned this up:  take a look at this bug report [#180 uninterned symbols not shared between forms in FAS file](http://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/bugs/180/).  I found it linked from [this mailing list discussion](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.lisp.gsll/128).  Is this relevant to your actual code?  Also see, perhaps, [#281 Lexical Binding in Toplevel PROGN (Clisp 2.35)](http://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/bugs/281/).

Comment: Yes, it appears that that's the bug. Heavens it's old. I guess I'll have to just use a workaround. Oh well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't show one of the lines that give you the error, so I can only guess, but the only thing that could cause this problem as far as I can see is that you are referring to the name of the symbol instead of the symbol itself when trying to call it.

If you were referring to the symbol itself, all your lisp implementation would have to do is lookup that symbol's `symbol-function`. Whether it's interned or not couldn't possibly matter.

May I ask why you haven't considered another way to hide the functions, i.e. a `labels` statement or defining the functions within a new package that exports only the one external function?

**EDIT**: The following example is copied literally from an interaction with the CLISP prompt.

As you can see, calling the function named by a gensym is working as expected.

```
[1]> (defmacro test ()
(let ((name (gensym)))
`(progn
(defun ,name () (format t "Hello!"))
(,name))))
TEST
[2]> (test)
Hello!
NIL
```

Maybe your code that's trying to call the function gets evaluated before the `defun`? If there's any code in the macro expansion besides the various `defun`s, it may be implementation-dependent what gets evaluated first, and so the behaviour of SBCL and CLISP may differ without any of them violating the standard.

**EDIT 2**: Some further investigation shows that CLISP's behaviour varies depending upon whether the code is interpreted directly or whether it's first compiled and then interpreted. You can see the difference by either directly `load`ing a Lisp file in CLISP or by first calling `compile-file` on it and then `load`ing the FASL.

You can see what's going on by looking at the first restart that CLISP offers. It says something like "Input a value to be used instead of (FDEFINITION '#:G3219)." So for compiled code, CLISP quotes the symbol and refers to it by name.

It seems though that this behaviour is standard-conforming. The following definition can be found in the HyperSpec:

> **function designator** *n.* a designator for a function; that is, an object that denotes a function and that is one of: a symbol (denoting the function named by that symbol in the global environment), or a function (denoting itself). The consequences are undefined if a symbol is used as a function designator but it does not have a global definition as a function, or it has a global definition as a macro or a special form. See also extended function designator.

I think an uninterned symbol matches the "a symbol is used as a function designator but it does not have a global definition as a function" case for unspecified consequences.

**EDIT 3**: (I can agree that I'm not sure whether CLISP's behaviour is a bug or not. Someone more experienced with details of the standard's terminology should judge this. It comes down to whether the function cell of an uninterned symbol - i.e. a symbol that cannot be referred to by name, only by having a direct hold on the symbol object - would be considered a "global definition" or not)

Anyway, here's an example solution that solves the problem in CLISP by interning the symbols in a throwaway package, avoiding the matter of uninterned symbols:

```
(defmacro test ()
  (let* ((pkg (make-package (gensym)))
         (name (intern (symbol-name (gensym)) pkg)))
    `(progn
       (defun ,name () (format t "Hello!"))
       (,name))))

(test)
```

**EDIT 4**: As Joshua Taylor notes in a comment to the question, this seems to be a case of the  (10 year old) [CLISP bug #180](http://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/bugs/180/).

I've tested both workarounds suggested in that bug report and found that replacing the `progn` with `locally` actually doesn't help, but replacing it with `let ()` does.

Comment: Good question. The reason I don't use `labels` or inline the functions (which is what I did originally) is that the single generated function in such a case is so large (> 30,000 lines) that the compiler runs out of memory and can't compile it.

Comment: See my edit to the original question for an example.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the `defun`s are definitely in the correct order. The calls happen after the definitions.

Comment: One difference between the example you've given and what I'm dealing with is that I don't call the function with the uninterned name directly. Rather, I call the top-level function, which in turn calls one or more functions with uninterned names. Using your example, I tested a more analogous case from the REPL, and it still worked. Hmm...

Comment: Regarding your second edit: I don't think it does conform. The standard defines the semantics of the language, but your comparing it to some intermediate form that CLISP happens to compile the language to. The fact is, the symbols processed by the evaluator for the `defun` and the call(s) to it are the same symbols. That fact seems to get lost in the form that CLISP compiles the code into.

Comment: I agree with @nbtrap about this.  The bit about symbols having global definition doesn't have anything to do with them being interned or not.  What it means is that _local_ functions (i.e., defined with `flet` and `label` can't be referenced by symbols.  You can't do `(flet ((foo () ...)) (funcall 'foo))` and have the symbol `foo` designate the function defined by `flet`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I'll look more into it and file a bug if I have to.

Comment: @Rörd, the suggestion to use a throwaway package is a good idea. Thank you.

Comment: @Rörd Looking at the compilation was a good track.  I found some bug reports and mentioned them in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19160858/why-cant-clisp-call-certain-funtions-with-uninterned-names-solved?noredirect=1#comment28350854_19160858) on the main question, but perhaps (since you've got the accepted answer), you can add the links into your answer.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: I have added the link to the main bug report to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can most certainly define functions whose names are uninterned symbols.  For instance:

```
CL-USER> (defun #:foo (x)
           (list x))
#:FOO
CL-USER> (defparameter *name-of-function* *)
*NAME-OF-FUNCTION*
CL-USER> *name-of-function*
#:FOO
CL-USER> (funcall *name-of-function* 3)
(3)
```

However, the [sharpsign colon](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dhe.htm) syntax introduces a new symbol each time such a form is read read:

> #: introduces an uninterned symbol whose name is symbol-name. Every time this syntax is encountered, a distinct uninterned symbol is created. The symbol-name must have the syntax of a symbol with no package prefix.

This means that even though something like

```
CL-USER> (list '#:foo '#:foo)
;=> (#:FOO #:FOO)
```

shows the same *printed* representation, you actually have two different symbols, as the following demonstrates:

```
CL-USER> (eq '#:foo '#:foo)
NIL
```

This means that if you try to call such a function by typing `#:` and then the name of the symbol naming the function, you're going to have trouble:

```
CL-USER> (#:foo 3)
; undefined function #:foo error
```

So, while you can call the function using something like the first example I gave, you can't do this last one.  This can be kind of confusing, because the *printed representation* makes it look like this is what's happening.  For instance, you could write such a factorial function like this:

```
(defun #1=#:fact (n &optional (acc 1))
  (if (zerop n) acc
      (#1# (1- n) (* acc n))))
```

using the special reader notation `#1=#:fact` and `#1#` to later refer to the same symbol.  However, look what happens when you print that same form:

```
CL-USER> (pprint '(defun #1=#:fact (n &optional (acc 1))
                    (if (zerop n) acc
                        (#1# (1- n) (* acc n)))))

(DEFUN #:FACT (N &OPTIONAL (ACC 1))
  (IF (ZEROP N)
      ACC
      (#:FACT (1- N) (* ACC N))))
```

If you take that printed output, and try to copy and paste it as a definition, the reader creates *two* symbols named "FACT" when it comes to the two occurrences of `#:FACT`, and the function won't work (and you might even get undefined function warnings):

```
CL-USER> (DEFUN #:FACT (N &OPTIONAL (ACC 1))
           (IF (ZEROP N)
               ACC
               (#:FACT (1- N) (* ACC N))))

; in: DEFUN #:FACT
;     (#:FACT (1- N) (* ACC N))
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: #:FACT
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     #:FACT
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition
```

Comment: In my original question, I tried to make it clear that I understood this and that this is not the problem.

Comment: I did see "The two instances of #:G75735 are definitely the same symbol--not two different symbols with the same name." but I wasn't clear how you were trying to _call_ the functions.  Sorry for any confusion.  The code that I've posted with functions with uninterned names works in CLISP, though.  Can you come up with a minimal working example that we can try in CLISP as well?

Comment: Yeah, perhaps I wasn't clear enough. The code I give in the original post is from the macro expansion--it's not something the reader ever sees.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I get the issue right. For me it works in CLISP.

I tried it like this: using a macro for creating a function with a GENSYM-ed name.

```
(defmacro test ()  
  (let ((name (gensym)))  
    `(progn  
       (defun ,name (x) (* x x))  
       ',name)))
```

Now I can get the name `(setf x (test))` and call it `(funcall x 2)`.

Comment: It turns out this is a [longstanding bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/bugs/180/) in CLISP.  It looks like if you had, instead of `',name` as the last form put, e.g., `(,name 45)`, and put `(test)` in a file, and then _compiled_ and loaded that file, you might have reproduced the error.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Actually it works. If I replace `',name` with `(,name 45)` and save it in "test.lisp" I can call `(load (compile-file "test.lisp"))` and `(test)` gives 2025. I use GNU CLISP 2.49 under Mac OS X 10.5.8.

Comment: I hadn't tested it either, obviously.  Maybe if rather than putting in a direct call, you were to define some other function that called it?  And tried calling that after compiling and loading?  The bug report makes it looks like it shouldn't take too much modification to break things. :)

Comment: Yeah, here's an example that shows the bug http://pastebin.com/ux40R8uE . Just put it in a file, compile and load, and then call `(frob)`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor It doesn't look like an error to me. The function `(frob)` isn't defined because the name of `(defun ,frob () 42)` is expanded into an #:FROB792 or something like this. But I can call `(call-frob)` and get 42.

Comment: Sorry, I miswrote.  Don't call `(frob)`, call `(call-frob)` which should call the pseudo-`frob`, and _that_ has the error.  I wrote too quickly.  The code reproduces the bug, though.  I just had a bug in my description. :)  Here's a paste with better instructions: http://pastebin.com/pBTUJr5B .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is perfectly fine defining functions that have names that are unintenred symbols. The problem is that you cannot then call them "by name", since you can't fetch the uninterned symbol by name (that is what "uninterned" means, essentially).

You would need to store the uninterned symbol in some sort of data structure, to then be able to fetch the symbol. Alternatively, store the defined function in some sort of data structure.

Comment: I am not trying to call them "by name". I am calling a different function by name which in turn calls the ones with uninterned names.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, [CLISP bug 180](http://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/bugs/180/) isn't actually an ANSI CL conformance bug. Not only that, but evidently, ANSI Common Lisp is itself so broken in this regard that even the `progn` based workaround is a courtesy of the implementation.

Common Lisp is a language intended for compilation, and compilation produces issues regarding the identity of objects which are placed into compiled files and later loaded ("externalized" objects). ANSI Common Lisp requires that literal objects reproduced from compiled files are only *similar* to the original objects. ([CLHS 3.2.4 *Literal Objects in Compiled Files*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_bd.htm)).

Firstly, according to the definition similarity ([3.2.4.2.2 Definition of Similarity](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_bdbb.htm)), the rules for uninterned symbols is that similarity is name based. If we compile code with a literal that contains an uninterned symbol, then when we load the compiled file, we get a symbol which is similar and not (necessarily) the same object: a symbol which has the same *name*.

What if the same uninterned symbol is inserted into two different top-level forms which are then compiled as a file? When the file is loaded, are those two similar to *each other* at least? No, there is no such requirement.

But it gets worse: there is also no requirement that two occurrences of the same uninterned symbol *in the same form* will be externalized in such a way that their relative identity is preserved: that the re-loaded version of that object will have the same symbol object in all the places where the original was.  In fact, the definition of similarity **contains no provision for preserving the circular structure and substructure sharing**. If we have a literal like `'#1=(a b . #1#)`, as a literal in a compiled file, there appears to be no requirement that this be reproduced as a circular object with the same graph structure as the original (a graph isomorphism). The similarity rule for conses is given as naive recursion: two conses are similar if their respective `car`s and `cdr`s are similar.   (The rule can't even be evaluated for circular objects; it doesn't terminate).

That the above works is because of implementations going beyond what is required in the spec; they are providing an extension consistent with ([3.2.4.3 Extensions to Similarity Rules](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_bdc.htm)).

Thus, purely according to ANSI CL, we cannot expect to use macros with gensyms in compiled files, at least in some ways. The expectation expressed in code like the following runs afoul of the spec:

```
(defmacro foo (arg)
   (let ((g (gensym))
         (literal '(blah ,g ,g ,arg)))
      ...))

(defun bar ()
  (foo 42))
```

The `bar` function contains a literal with two insertions of a gensym, which according to the similarity rules for conses and symbols need not reproduce as a list containing two occurrences of the same object in the second and third positions.

If the above works as expected, it's due to "extensions to the similarity rules".

So the answer to the "Why can't CLISP ..." question is that although CLISP does provide an extension for similarity which preserves the graph structure of literal forms, it doesn't do it across the entire compiled file, only within individual top level items within that file. (It uses `*print-circle*` to emit the individual items.) The bug is that CLISP doesn't conform to the best possible behavior users can imagine, or at least to a better behavior exhibited by other implementations.